# Update Query not working in Android Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

My Java code   Update Data base Table

```
String qq="UPDATE ChallanItems SET Recieve ="+str+" WHERE ItemNo = "+code;
                    Log.d("Qry", qq);
                     myDbHelper.updatequery(qq);
```

updatequery method

```
public void updatequery(String qry)
    {
        Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery(qry, null);


        Log.d("Up", ""+c.getCount());
    }
```

When i updated Data base the count return 0 and table not updated

I am using this Also but not work

```
String qq="UPDATE ChallanItems SET Recieve ="+str+" WHERE ItemNo = "+"'"+code+"'";
```

Please Help Me how i can fix this problem

Thanks In Advance

Comment: use `sqLiteDatabase.update(YOUR_TABLE, where clause, YOUR_VALUES);`. YOUR_VALUES is the object of `ContentValues`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `execSQL()` for such SQL and not `rawQuery()`.

`rawQuery()` just compiles the SQL but does not run it. You'd need to call one of the `move...()` methods on the returned `Cursor` to execute a step of the compiled SQL program.

`execSQL()` both compiles and runs the SQL program.

There's also possibly a syntax problem with your literals - use parameters i.e. `?` placeholders in SQL and `String[]` bind arguments to be safe.

Answer (score 2):

To update sqlite query change

```
 Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery(qry, null);
```

to this

```
myDataBase.execSQL(qry);
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use this:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("Recieve", str);
db.update("ChallanItems", values2, "ItemNo = ?", new String[] { code });
```